# Fast Tests: How to create instances of classes without using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm running rspec tests for a helper class. To speed them up, I want avoid loading FactorGirl and Rails.

My helper class currently instantiates objects from the User Class and Project class using Factory Girl.  For example:

```
describe '#show_follower_pic(user)' do
  it 'should show the profile pic when the user has one' do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, profile_pic_source: 'facebook',facebook_uid: "22331111", facebook:  {"info"=>{"image"=>"test_image.png"}} )
    show_follower_pic(user).should == "test_image.png" 
  end
```

How do I create fake classes for user and project that are only existant withint the realm of this particular test file (and not the larger test suite)?

Comment: Can you clarify your objectives here? Is it faster tests you want, or atomic data sets between specs? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Mocking is one possibility, another is a simple wipe of the data in an after(:all) block in your spec, or you could replace FactoryGirl with another library e.g. Fabrication. Determining what to recommend will be easier if you let us know what your primary objective is.

Comment: I'm trying to speed up my tests.  I figured that the fewer classes my tests loaded, the quicker each would run.

Comment: OK, thanks. I/O is probably the bottleneck rather than loading classes (unless by 'loading classes' you mean instantiating model objects?) so you could look into using mocks or stubs in your specs. RSpec has its own mocking capabilities or it can use other mocking libraries e.g. Mocha, RR, FlexMock etc. But you should consider the extra work involved in mocking. Atomicity, rather than performance, is the usual reason to use mocking.